# Packet loss caused by OpenSSL? Weird CPU usage

Tags: c, linux, openssl, cpu-usage

I'm writing network application reading packets from UDP sockets and then decrypting them using OpenSSL.

The main function looks like this:

```
receive(){
    while(1){
        read(udp_sock);
        decrypt_packet();
    }
}
```

Program used to work fine until I added encryption. Now there's a lot of packets lost between kernel buffer and my application (netstat -su  - RcvbufErrors: 77123 and growing ;). Packets are rather big (60K) and I try to use it on 1Gbps ethernet (thus problem begins after exceeding 100Mbps)

Sounds normal - decryption taking too much time and packets are coming too fast. The problem is - CPU usage never exceeds 30% both on the sender and the receiver.

Problem disappears after commenting out this statement in decrypt_packet():
AES_ctr128_encrypt();

My question is - is it possible, that OpenSSL is using some set of instruction which are not count in to CPU usage (I use htop and Gnome system monitor)? If not what else can cause such packet loss is CPU power is still available for processing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using profiler I was able to solve the problem. OpenSSL is using special set of instructions, which are executed in special part of CPU. Shown CPU usage was low, but in fact it was occupied doing encryption, so my application couldn't read  system buffer fast enough.

I moved decryption to other thread which solved the problem. And now the thread handling all encryption is shown as using 0% CPU all the time.

Answer (score 2):

How many CPU cores does your system have? Is your code single threaded? It could be maxing out a single core and thus using only 25% of the available CPU.

Comment: I have 2 cores, but I posted usage per core, so my application is using 25% of power of one thread.